# linux find command operation

Tags: linux, find, command

My shell script find all files 90 days older

```
find /var/www/html/zip/data/*/*/*/*/* -type f -mtime +90
```

that returns the output like

```
/var/www/html/zip/data/2011/jan/11/333333/Photos/a.jpeg

/var/www/html/zip/data/2011/jan/11/333333/Photos/b.jpeg

/var/www/html/zip/data/2011/jan/11/333333/Photos/c.jpeg

/var/www/html/zip/data/2011/feb/11/333333/Photos/a.jpeg

/var/www/html/zip/data/2011/feb/11/333333/Photos/b.jpeg
```

What would i need to do to just fetch unique folder path from the above output using the same Find command so the output should be

```
/var/www/html/zip/data/2011/jan/11/333333/Photos

/var/www/html/zip/data/2011/feb/11/333333/Photos
```

So i believe there would need to append something in the above Find command but don't know what

**Note:** I would like to save the unique path in a variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
find /var/www/html/zip/data/*/*/*/*/* -type f -mtime +90 -printf "%h\n" | sort | uniq
```

Comment: I don't know how widely available `-printf` is, but my system doesn't appear to have it :(

Comment: Is it possible to save the unique result in a variable using the above command suggested by you?

Comment: Sure, assuming you're using bash: 

var=$(find /var/www/html/zip/data/*/*/*/*/* -type f -mtime +90 -printf "%h\n" | sort | uniq);
echo "$var"

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if `find` can do this directly, but you could always use `sed` to post-process the results:

```
find /var/www/html/zip/data/*/*/*/*/* -type f -mtime +90  | sed 's|/[^/]*$||'
```

Piping the results further through `uniq` should remove duplicates (you might need to first do `sort`, but I doubt it).

Comment: I missed one thing that i also want to save the unique path in a variable

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution this way

```
find /var/www/html/zip/data -type d -mtime +90 | uniq
```

The idea behind this is, whenever a file inside a folder is updated or modified, folder is also marked as modified. So in this case you will get all the folders which were not updated in last 90 days...

Answer (score 0):

Adding to jonathanasdf's answer,

You could may be add a for loop,

```
$i=1;
for uniq_dir in `find /var/www/html/zip/data/*/*/*/*/* -type f -mtime +90 -printf "%h\n" | sort | uniq`;
do
a[$i]=$uniq_dir;
let "i = $i + 1";
done;
```